# Spacy matching priority

Tags: nlp, spacy, matcher

I'm looking to create a physics pattern library with spacy:
I want to detect time and speed pattern. My aim is to stay flexible with those pattern.

```
time_pattern = [
    [
    {'LIKE_NUM': True, 'OP': '?'},
    {'LOWER':{'IN': ['time', 's','h','min']}},
    {'LOWER': {"IN": ['maximum','minimum','min','max']}, 'OP':'?'}
    ]
]
speed_pattern = [
    [
    {'LIKE_NUM': True, 'OP': '?'},
    {'LOWER':{"IN": ['km', 'm']}},
    {'IS_PUNCT': True},
    {'LOWER' : {"IN": ['h','hour','s','min']}}
    ]
]


matcher=Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate =True)
matcher.add("SPEED", speed_pattern)
matcher.add("TIME", time_pattern)

doc=nlp("a certain time, more about 23 min, can't get above 25 km/h")

for id_match, start, end in matcher(doc):
    match_label=nlp.vocab[id_match].text
    print(match_label, '<--', doc[start:end])
```

So far my code returns this collection of matches:

- TIME <-- time
- TIME <-- 23 min
- TIME <-- min
- SPEED <-- 25 km/h
- SPEED<-- km/h
- TIME <-- h

I want the matcher to match only once, and to match "23 min" rather than "min". Also would like the matcher not to match an element already matched ( for exemple "h" should not be matched because it already matched in "km/h"

Answer (score 1):

You can try add `greedy="LONGEST"` to `matcher.add()` to return only the longest (or `FIRST`) matches:

```py
matcher.add("SPEED", speed_pattern, greedy="LONGEST")
matcher.add("TIME", time_pattern, greedy="LONGEST")
```

But note that this doesn't handle overlaps across different match IDs:

```
TIME <-- 23 min
TIME <-- time
TIME <-- h
SPEED <-- 25 km/h
```

If you want to filter all of the matches, you can use `matcher(doc, as_spans=True)` to get the matches directly as spans and then use `spacy.util.filter_spans` to filter the whole list of spans to a list of non-overlapping spans with the longest spans preferred: https://spacy.io/api/top-level#util.filter_spans

```
[time, 23 min, 25 km/h]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as_spans=True` option with [`spacy.matcher.Matcher`](https://spacy.io/api/matcher#call) (introduced in spaCy v3.0):

```py
matches = matcher(doc, as_spans=True)
for span in spacy.util.filter_spans(matches):
    print(span.label_, "->", span.text)
```

From the documentation:

> Instead of tuples, return a list of [Span](https://spacy.io/api/span) objects of the matches, with the `match_id` assigned as the span label. Defaults to `False`.

See the Python demo:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens.doc import Doc
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
time_pattern = [
    [
        {'LIKE_NUM': True, 'OP': '?'},
        {'LOWER':{'IN': ['time', 's','h','min']}},
        {'LOWER': {"IN": ['maximum','minimum','min','max']}, 'OP':'?'}
    ]
]
speed_pattern = [
    [
        {'LIKE_NUM': True, 'OP': '?'},
        {'LOWER':{"IN": ['km', 'm']}},
        {'IS_PUNCT': True},
        {'LOWER' : {"IN": ['h','hour','s','min']}}
    ]
]

matcher=Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate =True)
matcher.add("SPEED", speed_pattern)
matcher.add("TIME", time_pattern)

doc=nlp("a certain time, more about 23 min, can't get above 25 km/h")

matches = matcher(doc, as_spans=True)
for span in spacy.util.filter_spans(matches):
    print(span.label_, "->", span.text)
```

Output:

```
TIME -> time
TIME -> 23 min
SPEED -> 25 km/h
```

Comment: So far so good. However if I add a "meter" pattern it will recognize it above the speed pattern... with I would like to avoid.
'
meter_pattern = [{"LIKE_NUM" : True, 'OP':"?"},
                 {"IS_PUNCT": True,'OP': "?"},
                 {"LOWER":{'IN':["m","km","meter","kilometer"]}}]
'
Shall I encapsulate the meter condition in a 'IF' or is there a better way?

Comment: @Shmou Of course, `speed` pattern is `{'LOWER':{"IN": ['km', 'm']}},`, look, it contains `m` and `km`.

Comment: I understand. I would then want the meter pattern to contain km or m but not followed by / 
Could I use {'LOWER' != /} ?

Comment: @Shmou Try somthing like `{'LOWER': '/', 'OP': '!'}`

Comment: So after a bit of tweaking the right pattern would be: {"LOWER":"/", "OP": '*'}